# sed command not working correctly and gives the error unknown command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to replace a string in a file using the SED command.
Here the command is \

```
sed -i 's/\\F\\//g' $filepath
```

this works completely fine and when I do the same thing in the below way

```
param=s/\\F\\//g
sed -i "'$param'" $filepath
```

it give this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

and some times other error saying path not found if I try to play with the syntax.

Thanks

Comment: please update the question with a sample input file (eg, 2-5 lines; some lines to be left alone, some lines to be changed) and the expected output

Comment: try escaping each of the backslashes; alternatively wrap the assignment in quotes (eg, `param='s/\\F\\//g'`); also, remove the single quotes from the `sed` call (ie, `sed -i "$param"`)

Answer (score 1):

Put the `param` as-is in a variable. Then use the variable, as a rule of thumb, always inside `"`.

```
param='s/\\F\\//g'
sed -i "$param" "$filepath"
```